# A Number Theoretic Game

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, contest-math

I got this question in an exam I was giving-

> Alice and Bob are playing a game. There are $n$ coins laid out on a
> circular table, at positions marked from $1$ to $n$. In each round,
> Alice picks a list of positions. Bob then looks at this list, and can choose to cyclically shift the coins on the table by any number of
> positions. Finally, the coins at the positions chosen by Alice are
> flipped. Alice wins the game if at some point, all coins have "Heads" on top. For what values of $n$ can Alice guarantee a win, regardless of the initial configuration of the coins?

My approach was to think that if there is such an $n$, then in some sense, it has some property that is invariant under "cyclical shifts". So, the divisors of $n$ may play an important role. Especially, prime numbers may get involved as well. But, that's all the intuition I have. Nothing significant clicked from it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you know that the person who asked can vote and/or mark one answer as "accepted"? Please see https://math.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: At the beginning of the Game are all heads down?

Comment: @miracle173 I don't think so.

Comment: Can you add an example gor such a Game so that i can Check of i Unterstand you correctly? I think for n=4 Alice will Alexas win

Answer (score 4):

Let's represent the coins with a vector in $Z_2^n$, with $0$ representing heads, $1$ representing tails.

Let $G$ be the group acting on $Z_2^n$ generated by a cyclic permutation of the basis vectors.

Let $V$ be the set of all configuration from which Alice is guaranteed a win.

The game is equivalent to the following: Alice presents Bob with a collection of sequences $s_i$ of vectors, subject to some restrictions, from which Bob selects one. Alice can win from configuration $v$ if every sequence available to Bob satisfies $\sum s_i = v$.

Note that if $S$ and $T$ is a valid set of sequences of vectors for Alice to present to Bob (a "valid play"), then the set $U$ of concatenations of a sequence from $S$ with a sequence from $T$ is also a valid play.

Theorem: $V$ is a vector space.

Proof:

Note that $0\in V$.

Suppose $u$ and $v$ are in $V$. Then $u+v\in V$ also. This is because Alice has valid plays $S$ and $T$ for which every sequence $s_i\in S$ has $\sum s_i=\{u\}$ and every sequence $t_i\in T$ has $\sum t_i=\{v\}$. Then, let $U$ be the set of concatenations of sequences in $S$ and $T$, and note that for every $u_k\in U$, $\sum u_k=\sum s_i+\sum t_j=u+v$.

This is enough to prove $V$ is a vector space, since the field has characteristic 2.

Note that $V$ must be a union of orbits of $G$. Given an orbit $A\subseteq V$, one of the following must be true:

- either $A=\{0\}$
- Alice has a valid play $S$ such that for every sequence $s_i\in S$, no subsequence $s_1+\dots+s_k$ of $s$ has $a+s_1+\dots+s_k\in A$ for any $a\in A$.

Otherwise, Bob can force a stalemate by repeatedly visiting $A$.

The latter statement is equivalent to the following: if Alice can win, then for every subsequence $s_j$ of every $s_i\in S$, $\sum s_j\neq\{0\}$.

Hence, each move of the game removes a collection of orbits from $V$.

The subspace of possible configurations after $k$ moves is still a vector space. [Proof: exercise] and is still a union of orbits of $G$. Hence, there is a sequence of subspaces $V = V_0, V_1, V_2,..., V_m = \{0\}$ representing the possible configurations of the game after each of Alice's optimal moves (the fact that $m$ might vary from game to game doesn't change this. Either allow $V_i=V_j$, or assume Bob is playing optimally to maximise the length of the game).

It's better to renumber these subspaces: $W_k = V_{m-k}$, so $W_0=\{0\}$, and $W_m=V$.

Then, I think you can make good progress by asking:

- What could $W_1$ possibly be?
- Now you know that, what could $W_2$ possibly be?

I have a proof that $W_1=\langle (1,1,1...,1)\rangle$. I'm almost certain that $W_2$ only exists if $n$ is even, and equals $\langle(1,1,...,1), (1,0,1,0,....,1,0)\rangle$. I haven't tried to work out $W_3$ yet.

I have a sneaking suspicion that $V=Z_2^n$ if and only if $n$ is a power of 2, but that's just a vague feeling at this stage.

Comment: See also [n buttons on a table](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/80371/20814) in Puzzling SE.

Comment: That's neat. It's the same as this one would be if Alice were playing blind.